# How do I use swipeable tabs in a widget as a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

Components of this question are online, but there is nothing that implements them all. I would like to create a main activity that has a section of it (which will be a fragment) that contains swipeable tabs. The image below illustrates how the section will look. I am so new to Android, I'm not sure how to code both my main activity, fragment activity, and all my tabbed views into activities (I read each tab section should have its own activity).

I also do not know which widgets or layouts to use in my activity main layout or the fragment layouts. Like what widget should I use, TabHost/TabWidget? Although I heard TabHost is depreciated. How do I get the tabs to swipe? In the image below, the gray area is where images will be in each tab, so the user should be able to swipe those left or right, and the tab will change on its own.

See, most tutorials tell you how to use swipeable tabs in the ActionBar,  but I don't want it to be that high on the screen. Just inside of a fragment widget as the image shows. Thanks for any suggestions. The more step-by-step the better, as I am still a beginner. Thank you very much.

[image: main activity with tab widget]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: thanks Ankit, but this is part of my difficulty, I see this stuff, but then get lost and don't know which parts would best suit my needs. even if someone on S.O. could show me an outline of the steps they might take, it would break it down into tasks i could focus on separately. but the Android developer pages are good for enhancements, but i somehow always feel like something is missing when i read them. maybe this will improve the better i get with Android.

Comment: NP. Its really difficult to break these things into steps as ViewPager, FragmentPagerAdapter, Activities, and Fragments are all interlinked. But I'll try to write an answer an explain these steps. Meanwhile you figure out which kind of tabs you want to implement. AFAIK tab functionality can be implemented using two ways: 1 using ViewPager(eg Google Play tabs). 2 using Action Bar Navigation. I personally prefer using ViewPager.

Comment: thanks Ankit, that is very nice of you to consider the steps. i definitely don't want anything in the Action Bar, so i think that ViewPager sounds about right. it is true, to consider how to add things to all the different files is tricky. i know there will be a main activity that "hosts" the fragment activity widget. the fragment will have the code for all the swiping of tabs. then in the layout, there will be a main layout, again, that refers to the fragment layout where all the tab widgets are... but i am not clear which methods, classes, or xml tags to use for all this. thanks in advance!

Comment: FragmentPagerAdapter will probably be needed too, as i hear this kind of thing needs an adapter. just not sure where or how exactly. :(

Comment: I wasn't able to describe that in steps(a common problem with programmers I guess :P), so I wrote a small snippet. Hope that helps :)

Comment: If you think your problem is solved, please accept one of the answers...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example of **Scrolling Tabs**. Hope this helps you a bit.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    // used ActionBarActivity from v7 support library, 
    // for backward compatibility 

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            // each page corresponds to a new fragment
            // I'll return the same fragment for now
            return new MyFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // return no of pages
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // return the page title
            return "Tab " + position;
        }
    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        public MyFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml** is just the hello world fragment. You will need to customize the `PagerTitleStrip` to make it look like a tab. For that I really love this [library](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip).

Comment: thanks so much Ankit, that is definitely a working example of swipe, but actually it is of scrolling tabs, which i only wanted the view in the fragment to be swipeable. scrolling tabs would be great if i had lots of tabs, but i will only have 5, so it would be better to keep them all visible in the view. very nice job though! i might save this in case i need it one day. :) any idea how to make the tabs fixed? then the swipe only moves from one tab to the next. nonetheless, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: NP. couldn't get back to you earlier. You might have probably solved the problem by now. It might help someone else. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small example of **Fixed tabs**:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this).setText("Tab " + i));

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                actionBar.selectTab(actionBar.getTabAt(arg0));
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    private static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            // each page corresponds to a new fragment
            // I'll return the same fragment for now
            return new MyFragment();
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // return no of pages
            return 5;
        }
    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        public MyFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```